# Magento 2 short search keywords

Tags: magento2, search

The Magento 2.1.7 store contains multiple products with names like FA-7

But searching with the exact productname as keyword gives no results.
Searching with keyword like SKRF-7 give multiple products as result with productname starting with SKRF.

In Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search, we set the minimal Query Length on 2 characters.
Cache cleared, reindexed, but no results.

Anyone have a clue what could be the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably this is a limitation on the database.
The full text search index has its own minimum word length.
I may be wrong, but I think the default is 4.
[Here are more details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) on how you can change that.